# Google Apps Script - Combining Firstname and Lastnames to get emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to combine the firstname and lastname in my spreadsheet and get unique email ids with it, also concatenating it with a dot(.) , an example is john.harris@unixxx.com

Also i realised that if i'm to generate this, some students that have same names,would have the same email accounts,How can i resolve this? Can somebody please help out with a code to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGlMNW9ZSnVJQVVSZHI2cThyNU9qRFE) that I use for this purpose... you can try if it suits your needs...

it's mainly in french but that shouldn't be an issue, it's quite elementary and easy to translate.